# How can I implement tabs in Flutter similar to this?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make something like this? "Popular", "upcoming" ... at the top, and by swiping right to see other information. It is better to use ListView or other Widget?
[image: App]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called tabs. You need to implement Flutter's TabBar class to get something similar. Flutter's TabBar is the best widget to use. This is the [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) to the Flutter docs where they explain how to use Flutter's inbuilt tab bar. If you need a tutorial, you can find it [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs) in the Flutter cookbook.

You can watch this [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4K2ImlMww&ab_channel=diegoveloper) to see how to implement a TabBar with ListViews to get this:
[image]